# Windows Task Scheduler SendKeys Save CSV

Tags: excel, vba, windows, web-scraping, windows-task-scheduler

*UPDATE* SendKeys only seems to work if I click on the Window. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I am trying to automate downloading a CSV file from a website. The vbs file when executed runs perfectly and is able to click save. I added this file to the Task Scheduler and when I click 'run', it works perfectly. However, when I schedule a time when logged in on my computer and it runs automatically, it gets to the very end and is not able to click save in order to download the CSV.

The "Save As" prompt will glow this shade of gold and the file will eventually end without downloading the file.

Here is an image of the "Save As" bar as well as the code with the user/pw removed so it cannot be run. Any suggestions or ideas as to why this may be happening?

[image: Search Bar Gold Message]

[image: Windows Task Scheduler Event]

```
Sub Login()

Dim aFile As String
aFile = "C:\Users\MKyle\Downloads\Transactions_export.csv"
If Len(Dir$(aFile)) > 0 Then
     Kill aFile
End If

Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set i = New InternetExplorer
i.Visible = True

i.Navigate ("https://app.paystone.com/transaction")

Do While i.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set idoc = i.Document

idoc.all.q_username.Value = "user"
idoc.all.q_password.Value = "pw"

Dim ele As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim eles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Set eles = idoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each ele In eles
    If ele.ID = "submit" Then
        ele.Click
    Else
    End If
    
Next ele

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Set btns = idoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each btn In btns
    If btn.innerText = " Search " Then
        btn.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    
Next btn

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Set vals = idoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each v In vals
    Debug.Print v.innerText
    If v.innerText = " Export " Then
        v.Click
        
        Set subs = idoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
        For Each s In subs
            If s.innerText = " CSV" Then
                s.Click
                Exit For
            End If
            
        Next s
        
        Exit For
    End If
    
Next v

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))
Application.SendKeys "%{S}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:25"))

i.Visible = False
i.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried changing IE setting to not prompt? as in 'https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/how-can-i-configure-ie-to-save-as-file-instead-of/5a8cbbb1-126b-495e-ab2f-f404cb0824ed'

Comment: I have not tried that. I will look into it, I'm guessing that would work

Comment: Let us know....

Comment: It looks like the automatic prompting for downloads option has been removed from Internet Explorer. I have File Download, Font Download and .Net Framework enabled. So haven't been able to disable the prompt yet